# problems with the multi condition in C

Tags: c

I wrote code to count operations as `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, factorial and others. Problem  is that my code works good for one time . It displays :

> Zadajte operaciu

It means "write what you want to do". But after first time when cycle is over. It displays :

> Zadajte operaciu:Zadajte operaciu:

twice and I don´t know why.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int a,b,vysledok;
char s;
do{

printf("Zadajte operaciu:");

s=getchar();
if(s=='+' || s== '-' ||s== '*' || s=='/' ||s== '^')
{
    puts("Operacia je binarna.\nZadaj prvy operand: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    puts("Zadaj druhy operand: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

     switch (s){
    case '+':
        printf("Vysledok je %d.\n",a+b);
        break;
    case '-':

        printf("Vysledok je %d.\n",a-b);
        break;
    case '/':

        if(b==0)
            puts("CHYBA: nulou sa delit neda.\n");
        else
            printf("Vysledok je %d.\n",a/b);
        break;
    case '*':
         printf("Vysledok je %d.\n",a*b);
        break;
    case '^':
        for(a;a>0;a--)
            b=b*b;
        printf("Vysledok je %d.\n",b);
        break;
}}
 else if(s== '!' || s=='s')
{
    puts("Operacia je unarna.\nZadaj prvy argument: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
     switch (s){

    case '!':
        vysledok=a;
        for(a;a>0;a--)
            vysledok=vysledok*a;
        printf("Vysledok je %d.\n",vysledok);
        break;
    case 's':
        vysledok=sqrt(a);
        printf("Vysledok je %f.\n",(float)vysledok);
        break;
}}
else if(s=='q')
    puts("Zadany prikaz quit. Ukoncujem.");

} while (s!='q');

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After entering values , you press the enter key (`\n`). This character stays in the `stdin`. In the second iteration,`getchar` gets the `\n` character and as it does not fulfill the condition in the `if` after it,the body of the `if` does not get executed and the next iteration starts as the condition in the `while` is true,thus printing it twice.

To remove the character,you need to [clear your `stdin`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, now i understand where was problem :)

Answer (score 1):

just use the function getch() before s= getchar();

```
getch();
s=getchar();
```

that might help you or you can use

```
scanf(" %c",&s);
```

instead of s=getchar();

don't forget to put space before %c

Comment: I used scanf and it works now. getch() before it didn ´t work well because i need to put operation twice . :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to empty your buffer after each call to getchar so do as follows :

```
s = getchar();
while((s = getchar()) != EOF & s != '\n');
```

instead of an alone :

```
s = getchar();
```